# What are things to be taken care of before putting your app in android market?

Tags: android-market

I have developed a small android app. I am planning to release it in Google Android market. What are the things I should be aware of before doing this?

Comment: See this link http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html#releaseready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, broad question, but I will give it a crack.
Since I am not exactly sure about your specific concern, I will include any issues I can remember.

1. Decide if you want to release it as a free or paid app.
2. Decide if you want to display ads in the app.
3. Make sure you have done a fair amount of testing, as you will
   get 50 negative comments for every 1 positive comment.
4. most of you downloads will occur within the first week or so, while the app is still new.
   Then you will only get users that find your app based upon searches, or popularity if it gets downloaded frequently.  So make sure your keywords are effective.

hopefully this helps.

Comment: you should fix the formatting of your answer